# How to convert dataframe names stored in a pandas list , in a format that can be used with concat

Tags: python, pandas

trying to concatenate data frames from a list called '`df_list`' containing names of pandas dataframes? the list is generated through a looping process.

```
df_list = ['x_0', 'x_1', 'x_2', 'x_3']

xyz=pd.concat((x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3), axis=0)
xyz
```

I can always concatenate it like as above manually. However since the number of dataframes can increase or decrease in an automated process. How do i dynamically use this list with concat function?

This doesnt work => `xyz=pd.concat(df_list , axis=0)`

Tried converting df_list to series but that also doesnt work.
Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Your df_list contains names of dataframes which are strings instead, try storing the dataframe variables in the list.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
xyz = pd.concat([globals()[df] for df in df_list], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join two lists with below:

```
df_list1 = ['x_0', 'x_1', 'x_2', 'x_3']
df_list2 = ['x_0', 'x_1', 'x_2', 'x_3']
xyz = (df_list1, df_list2)
xyz
```

out=

```
(['x_0', 'x_1', 'x_2', 'x_3'], ['x_0', 'x_1', 'x_2', 'x_3'])
```